# Android App How to rotation screen orientation temporarily

Tags: android, screen-rotation

Is there any way to temporarily stop rotating the screen, perform a restore operation?
Request can not be turned off gravity sensor, it only prohibits the rotating screen.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the orientation change you need to tell Android that you want to handle it by yourself.

To do so, add the following to your activity in the mainfest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Now override the following in the Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If you don't load a new layout here you will just keep the orientation.

Further details you can find here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html